# SystemC error, using visual c++ 2008

Tags: c++, vhdl, hdl, systemc, secure-coding

I am using systemC with visual C++ 2008. I wrote a simple hello world program. However I am getting this error repeatedly:

> warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe.

Why this is happening? I would appreciate any help.

Comment: It's a warning, not an error.

Answer (score 4):

The compiler warns against `sprintf()` use because it may cause buffer overflow since it doesn't check buffer's limit. Instead, use `snprintf()` which never fills the buffer beyond the passed-in limit.

This advice is also given by the [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf):

> Because sprintf() and vsprintf() assume an arbitrarily long string, callers must be 
>   careful not to overflow the actual space; this is often impossible to assure. Note that 
>   the length of the strings produced is locale-dependent and difficult to predict. Use 
>   snprintf() and vsnprintf() instead (or asprintf(3) and vasprintf(3)).

Comment: "this is often impossible to assure" only if you're an idiot. People who have been coding in C for long enough know the difference between truly insecure stuff (like `gets`, or `scanf("%s")` where you don't control the input) and stuff like `sprintf` where you _can_ make it safe. Everyone else should go back to using VB :-) I always turn off these warnings with a #define since I _know_ what I'm doing.

Comment: I do agree that `gets()` and `sprintf()` fall into different categories when it comes to potential for vulnerabilities, but there is a danger in using `sprintf()` which you have not mentioned and which is connected with maintenance: it's easy to forget to update buffer size when you modify the format string or other parameters passed to `sprintf()`.

Answer (score 0):

It's insecure because -  [From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybk95axf%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> There is no way to limit the number of characters written, which means that code using sprintf is susceptible to buffer overruns. Consider using the related function _snprintf, which specifies a maximum number of characters to be written to buffer, or use _scprintf to determine how large a buffer is required. Also, ensure that format is not a user-defined string.

Comment: It's not insecure, it *may* be insecure.

Comment: Yes, it's only insecure if you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: @skeptic: "thanks everyone" is best expressed ["by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer."](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)